# CSS Box-Shadow adds arbitrary white border to Div

Tags: border, css

I'm adding a box shadow to an element containing an img and it's creating an arbitrary white border on the bottom of the element. No border is being applied via CSS (and I even tried overriding with `border:none;` without luck). When applied to the image directly, it appears properly. But when applied to a div containing an image, the border appears.

Any help is grealty appreciated.

```
<style>
html,body,div,img {margin:0; padding:0;} 
body {padding:50px;}

.badge_image {
  float:left;
  /* css drop shadow */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px #a2958a;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px #a2958a;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px #a2958a; 
}
</style>

<div class="badge_image">
    <img src="badge-image.jpg" height="75" width="75" />
</div>  

<br clear="all" /><br clear="all" />

<img src="badge-image.jpg" height="75" width="75" class="badge_image" /><!-- works fine -->
```

Comment: They look exactly the same for me in Chrome 14. http://jsbin.com/eqamid/edit#preview

Comment: @Thomas viewing your link, in Chrome 14.0.835.29 on Windows 7, shows the border on the first image

Comment: Whoa, never mind. It does show up. It just doesn't show in the preview pane on the JSBin link, my bad.

Comment: you guys were crazy quick with the answers, thanks! also of interest, in my demo code i was using an HTML doctype...if switched to an xhtml 1.0 transitional all was good. crazy stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try display block for image.

```
.badge_image img {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Kraz basically said the same thing, but marked this one for simplicity sake

Comment: 8 years later, still an issue :) Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 4):

Either :

1. Add a `display:block;` to your `img`.
2. Define a `line-height` of `0px` on your `div`.

An image is an inline element, so there is space for text, leaving that line.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ3fF/1/)

Answer (score 2):

The `display: block` solution doesn't work for me, in a couple of cases, but putting this on the same element as the box-shadow works.

```
backdrop-filter: blur(0px);
```

I'm unsure why this works, but it does.

Answer (score -1):

And one more way to achieve this is to add `virtical-align: top;` to an `img`.