# iPad CSS 3 box-shadow bug

Tags: ipad, css

When I open the following bug on iPad Safari, is there a white border before the shadow..
Does anyone know this bug and a solution?
HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/RJxBu/

```
box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

Here is a screenshot how it looks on the iPad:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Box-Shadow adds arbitrary white border to Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001889/css-box-shadow-adds-arbitrary-white-border-to-div)

Comment: Looks fine on iPad in Safari for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.test {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: No this is no solution, when you do box-shadow on an image and zoom in and out you can see the effect..

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a drawing bug where the shadow color should be blending with the img edge, but isn't. Adding a background-color to the img that matches the shadow color fixes the problem:

```
.test {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1); /* Has to be 1 alpha or it won't draw */
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border: 0px;
}
```

This will work on iOS5 and 6 on iPhone and iPad (untested otherwise). iOS6 has a bug where if an img has a background-color and a box-shadow with a spread of 0, the shadow will not draw. The only way I've found to fix this is to make sure the spread is non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a box shadow inset with a solid color to remove the white line on ipad. You may want to play with the negative -1 and -2 but this is what I use.

```
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px -2px 2px #000000, 5px 5px 4px 12px rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue once when the Box Shadow wasn't showing up on the iPad.

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

This worked for me. Hope that helps.

Try

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
```