# How to remove the border box-shadow provides?

Tags: html, css

So I have this 'floating-card' which has a box-shadow around it. On one side I want to put a colored border. But the box-shadow gives an extra white border. I want this removed but I dont know how. I want to keep the box-shadow. I tried several things including the answer of this question.

[CSS Box-Shadow adds arbitrary white border to Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001889/css-box-shadow-adds-arbitrary-white-border-to-div)

To show specifically what I want removed:

[image]
The little small white border on the left of the blue.

Here is a JSFiddle and the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/pg5omtqq/

```css
.floating-card {
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 5px solid blue;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px grey;
  margin: 1.0em;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-card">
  <h3 class="tile_title">Title</h3>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: To be clear, I want to keep the box-shadow. But have the small white border removed.

Comment: do you still need the box shadow and you wanted to remove it from the left end (blue colored end)?? or do you wanted to remove the box-shadow effect?

Comment: No I want to keep the box-shadow. I'll edit my question

Comment: I do not see it , zooming your image, this page of your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pg5omtqq/1/ does it show in a specific browser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will remove the shadow on the left

```
 -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 2px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 10px 2px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 10px 2px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

You can adjust this by using this generator box shadow.
source: https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

Comment: Little side note, it does not completely get rid of the white border on the left. This answer is just lacking the left box-shadow. Giving it a small box-shadow of 5px on the left, shows a extremely hard to see white border.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your CSS

```
box-shadow: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

remove left box-shadow by using below css.

```css
.floating-card{
  background-color: white;
  border-left: 5px solid blue;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px grey;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px grey;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px grey;
  margin: 1.0em;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-card">
    <h3 class="tile_title">Title</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 1px 10px grey;
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 1px 10px grey;
box-shadow: 2px 1px 10px grey;
```